# UIScrollView is going small than minimumZoomScale

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am `UIScrollView` and added `UIImageView` to it and set the delegate and implemented the delegate method

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that we want to zoom
    return self.imageView;
}
```

everything looks fine, I can pinch zoom in & out.

**problem is:** when I keep on pinching the image, the image will be too small and it will bounds back to `minimumZoomScale`. so I just want to stop pinch when it reaches `minimumZoomScale`.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off zoom bouncing for the scroll view:

```
scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
```

From the docs:

> If the value of this property is YES and zooming exceeds either the maximum or minimum limits for scaling, the scroll view temporarily animates the content scaling just past these limits before returning to them. If this property is NO, zooming stops immediately at one a scaling limits. The default is YES .

Sounds like this is what you want.

If you want bouncing on the max end but not the min end, you'll have to implement the delegate method `- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and reset the zoom scale in that method.

Comment: If this was the right answer, please accept it by selecting the tick mark next to the answer. This gives us both reputation points, and takes the question off the unanswered list.